# What is action and reward in a neural network which learns weights by reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, recurrent-neural-network

My goal is to predict customer churn. I want to use reinforcement learning to train a recurrent neural network which predicts a target response for its input.

I understand that the state is represented by the input to the network at each time, but I don't understand how the action is represented. Is it the values of weights which the neural network should decide to choose by some formulas?

Also, how should we create a reward or punishment to teach the neural network its weights as we don't know the target response for each input neurons?

Answer (score 2):

The aim of reinforcement learning is typically to maximize long term reward for an agent playing a game of sorts (a Markov Decision Process). In typical reinforcement learning usage, neural networks are used to approximate the Q-function. So, the network's input is the state **and action** (or a feature representations thereof), and the output is the value of taking that action in that state. Reinforcement learning algorithms like Q-learning provide the details on how to choose actions at a given time step, and also dictate how updates to the value function should be done.

It isn't clear how your specific goal of building a customer churn model might be formulated as a Markov Decision Problem. You could define your states to be statistics about customers' interactions with the company website, but it isn't clear what the actions might be, because it isn't clear what the agent is and what it can do. This is also why you are finding it difficult to define a reward function. The reward function should tell the agent if it's doing a good job. So, if we're imagining an MDP where the agent is trying to minimize customer churn, we might provide a negative reward proportional to the number of customers that turn over.

**I don't think you want to learn a Q-function.** I think it's more likely that you are interested simply in *supervised learning*, where you have some sample data and you want to learn a function that will tell you how much churn there will be. For this, you should be looking towards gradient descent methods and forward/backward propagation for training your neural network.